# Category page slow loading

Tags: category, configurable-product

I recently launched my new magento website altough I noticed long loading times when opening a page with multiple products.

The more products the page displays the longer the loading time is. For example: http://www.neflyx-webshop.com/dames/dream.html
Has a way longer load time than http://www.neflyx-webshop.com/dames/anna.html

I think it is because each product has many associated products but why does it slow down the loading that much? Is there anything I can do about this issue? Would caching help here?

Thanks!

EDIT: I figured out the slow load time is caused by the product swatches. I disabled them and the load time went to as little as 0.2 seconds. Does anyone know a fix for this? I believe swatches really add a lot of value to my website.

Comment: but for me both pages took equal time to load may be your internet is slow??

Comment: I am pretty sure it isn't my internet since I have tested it from a couple of different locations. Also the Magento profiler indicates a loading time of 7 seconds for the "Dream" category page and only 0.2 seconds for the "Anna" page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a great solution to my issue here: https://github.com/wigman/AjaxSwatches

It sped up the loading time with swatches by 20 times!